# Detect an unconnected pin on an MCP3008

Tags: python, mcp3008

I have a couple moisture sensors loosely connected to an MCP3008 and was wondering whether it was possible to detect if a sensor is unconnected. I then tried to detect it with the channel voltage in my little python script. I then quickly stumbled upon the problem of floating pins and tried connecting 10K pull-down resistors to every pin. But this only resulted in incorrect readings from the sensor which can only be resolved by multiplying the sensor reading with a value which is different for every sensor. I can now detect an unconnected sensor but I was wondering if there are any more elegant solutions to this problem? Preferably in Python

Comment: his is not a Pi question.

Comment: Mission impossible: How to detect open circuit: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/618029/how-can-a-dmm-measure-open-circuit-voltage